# Flexbox - Cater for 2,3 or 1 items per row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a basic flexbox implementation that handle 3 columns, if 2 or 1 columns are used then it automatically fills the space to handle it..

```css
.grid3 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.grid3-item {
    flex-basis: 33.333%;
    text-align: center;
    flex:1;
    background:grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid3">
    <div class="grid3-item">
        Some Content
    </div>
    <div class="grid3-item">
        Some Content
    </div>
    <div class="grid3-item">
        Some Content
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to make it so that if there are more than 3 columns then they will be handled on a new row, so for example 5 columns would looks like this

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this using flexbox?  The items are generated dynamically so I want to be able to handle any number of potential items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `flex-basis` along with `flex-grow: 1` for that:

```css
.grid3 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.grid3-item {
    flex: 1 0 33%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box
}
```

```html
<div class="grid3">
    <div class="grid3-item">Some Content</div>
    <div class="grid3-item">Some Content</div>
    <div class="grid3-item">Some Content</div>
    <div class="grid3-item">Some Content</div>
    <div class="grid3-item">Some Content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.grid3 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.grid3-item {
    flex: 1 0 26%;
    text-align: center;
    background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid3">
    <div class="grid3-item">Some Content</div>
    <div class="grid3-item">Some Content</div>
    <div class="grid3-item">Some Content</div>
    <div class="grid3-item">Some Content</div>
    <div class="grid3-item">Some Content</div>
</div>
```

The `flex: 1 0 26%` shorthand rule breaks down to this:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 0`
- `flex-basis: 26%`

With `flex-grow: 1` there's no need for `flex-basis` to be 33.333%.

Since `flex-grow` will consume free space on the row, `flex-basis` only needs to be large enough to enforce a wrap.

In this case, with `flex-basis: 26%` and `flex-shrink: 0`, a maximum of three items can exist on the line. (Plus, there's plenty of room for margins, if you want them.)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this is exactly what flexbox is for. You just needed a "min-width".

This works for any number of boxes that I try.

```css
.grid3 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.grid3-item {
    flex-basis: 33.333%;
    min-width: 33.3%;
    text-align: center;
    flex:1;
    background:grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid3">
    <div class="grid3-item">
        Some Content
    </div>
    <div class="grid3-item">
        Some Content
    </div>
    <div class="grid3-item">
        Some Content
    </div>
    <div class="grid3-item">
        Some Content
    </div>
    <div class="grid3-item">
        Some Content
    </div>
</div>
```